# eth.getPastLogs() requires exact match 32 byte value, how to get bignumber to emit?

Tags: web3js, events, bignumber

[the API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs) `eth.getPastLogs()` requires 4 topics to match the log indexing capabilities of the EVM.  It appears to require a full 32 byte number for the match to work.  i.e.

```
eth.getPastLogs((fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest', address '0xabc',
    topics: [ null, '0x25', null, null ] })
```

will not find a topic that has

```
`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025`
```

in it

but this will match said topic:

```
eth.getPastLogs((fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest', address '0xabc',
    topics: [ null,'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025', null, null ] })
```

So first question - is this a bug, and second question, how do I get bignumber.js to force an output of all 32 bytes?  toString(16) doesn't give me the leading zeros or the '0x'.   Do I have to write a special function or is there one there already in web3.js and I just can't find it?

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the above answer but it will soon be out of date because web3.js in v1.0 [exposes the padding](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#padleft) functions.  It's better not to reinvent the wheel.

So my code looks like this:

```
topic = '0x' + web3.utils.padLeft(new BigNumber(someNumber).toString(16), 64);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it a bug? Possibly, but if so it's a won't-fix: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/431

How to get the appropriate 32-byte padding for a BigNumber? As you suggest it feels like there should be a function to do this in web3.js, but the simple solution is just to do something like:

```
function bigNumberToPaddedBytes32(num) {
    var n = num.toString(16).replace(/^0x/, '');
    while (n.length < 64) {
        n = "0" + n;
    }
    return "0x" + n;
}
```

Comment: so in the absense of an ABI (such as with `getPastLogs`)everything is treated as bytes32... good to know...

Answer (score 0):

BigNumber `BN.j` library also have `length` argument in `toString(base, length)` method:

```
topic = '0x' + new web3.utils.BN(someNumber).toString(16, 64);
```